# Passing in an array of values to an express POST route

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, post, mongoose

I have a mongoose model called Todo that looks like this:

```
content: [{
    contentType: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    contentValue: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    }
}]
```

My express POST route looks like this:

```
app.post('/todos', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    var todo = new Todo({
        content: req.body.content

    });
    res.send(todo)
    //I am sending instead of sending the result for testing 
});
```

When I send int test data using Postman the content array is coming back empty "content": []

I have tried several formats of Body in postman including:

```
{
    "content[contentType]": "reminder",
    "content[contentValue]": "Will it blend"
}
```

and

```
{
    "content": {
       "contentType": "reminder",
       "contentValue": "Will it blend"
    }
}
```

However both come back with empty array.

```
{
  "content": []
}
```

Do I need to change something on my POST route and\or send in teh data in an alternate format?

Comment: i think you are not calling todo.save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

content here is a todo sub document, so you should treat it like the following:

```
app.post('/todos', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    var content = req.body.content;
    var todo = new Todo();

    todo.content.push(content);

    todo.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.json(todo.toJSON())
      //I am sending instead of sending the result for testing 
    });

});
```

See: [Mongoose SubDocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Comment: This was correct answer however as a sub-document it is not auto generating an ObjectID correctly. DO I need to generate manually and save it?

Comment: What do you expect and what is generating now?